# Government Spending vs. Investment Spending

Tags: gdp

What is the difference between government spending on physical capital and investment spending by government on physical capital?

Answer (score 1):

Government spending is the spending by the government on goods and services (non-capital goods). This means that the government buying physical capital would not be included in government spending, and would be included in investment spending.